# How to create WordPress Page that shows content of home page?

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to create a home page with url like this: **example.com/home** because the root domain has been deindexed by Google.

Comment: You have to write : rewrite rule for this.

Comment: I don't know how to do it, all help is greatly appreciated @VishalKamal

Comment: did you try to change url from wp-options from mysql

Answer (score 0):

Just go to wp-admin/options-general.php and at "Site Address (URL)" section enter desired URL.

[image]

p.s. don't edit WordPress URL field. Edit "Site Address (URL)" only.